# Como corrigir o erro de acentuação ao enviar um e-mail com php?

Tags: php

Estou tendo problemas com a acentuação ao enviar um e-mail com o php.
Este é o meu código em PHP

```
public function enviar_imovel(){

    $data['title'] = 'Enviar imóvel';
    $this->load->view('auth/enviar_imovel');

    if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {

        $nome = addslashes($_POST['nome']);
        $email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
        $contato = addslashes($_POST['contato']);
        $mensagem = addslashes($_POST['message']);

        $to = "atendimento@guiacorretors.com.br";
        $subject = "Um novo imovel foi enviado para ser analisado,";
        $body = "Nome: ". $nome. "\r\n".
                "Email: ". $email. "\r\n".
                "Contato: ". $contato. "\r\n".
                "Mensagem: ". $mensagem;
        $header = "From: atendimento@guiacorretors.com.br"."\r\n".
                  "Reply-to:".$email."\r\n".
                  "X=Mailer:PHP/".phpversion();


        if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$header)){
            echo("Email enviado com sucesso!");
        } else {
            echo("Email não pode ser enviado.");
        }
    }
}
```

E é assim que fica quando eu recebo um e-mail com acento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]